# files re-checked out from git repository with 'clean' filter end up with modified status

Tags: git, filter

I am trying to implement a rcs keyword substitution for git. The requirement is that the working copy has to be filtered before getting into git repo. So that after commit i have working copy with changes in my working tree which is the same as in the repo.

I tried t implement it using filters, hoping to re-checkout the file in a post-commit script. It worked in general, but ... after removing the file and checking it out it gets 'modified' status. And there is real difference, say in date or in commit id. So, I am lost. Besides it works with no problems with 'ident'

so, here is the snapshot of what i did:

```
.gitattribute --> *hpp filter=rcs-kwdsubst
.git/config --> [filter "rcs-kwdsubst"] clean=my-filter
%> git commit file.hpp -m "blah"
%> rm file.hpp
%> git checkout file.hpp
%> git status
    ... modified file.hpp ...
```

why??? how to fix it?

Comment: forgot to mention, if i only use .gitattribute --> *hpp ident, it works OK in the above scheme and modifies the $Id$ tag as expected, no modified status.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, at least partially. It looks like filters in git not only run at commit/checkout time but also at 'diff' and presumably at merge time. This is mess.

I assume that initial idea was to avoid some merge problems around versions by 'cleaning' the file to a 'standard' state in repository before committing, so that merge conflicts in version strings would naturally go away. It would only modify versions in checked out files.

Well, it created a different problem which undermines the idea of version control system:

1. every one on the team have *different* version of files.
2. there is no way to return to a specific past version, because files will differ at checkout.

I do not know if there is way to get around it without using own per-commit scripts. Neither filters nor hooks work, making it impossible to version files.